# smart-table page not reset to 1 on collection refresh

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have setup the [smart-grid](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#top) as per the documentation and everything is working fine. I am adding a new record in a modal dialog and on successful add of new record, I would like to refresh the smart-grid. I understand from the documentation that I just need to refresh the collection as I am using `st-safe-src` attrubute.

My issue is, Suppose, I am displaying 17 records and I am on page 2 now, and now I open the modal to add new record and close it after successfull addition, I am resetting the collection. But in this scenario, the page remains in page 2 only, and not getting reset to page 1. How to do that?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-pipe="getMasterJobs" st-safe-src="rowCollection" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-show="!isDataLoading">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
      <td>{{row.name}}</td>
      <td>{{row.description}}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" ng-click="editRow(row)" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">
          <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody ng-show="isDataLoading">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="text-center">Loading...</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot ng-hide="isDataLoading">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center" st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10" st-displayed-pages="displayedPages" colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I have this in my controller.js file:

```js
$scope.rowCollection = [];
$scope.isDataLoading = false;
//copy the references (you could clone ie angular.copy but then have to go through a dirty checking for the matches)
$scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);

$scope.getMasterJobs = function(tableState) {
  console.log(tableState);
  var start = 0;
  var length = 10;
  var pagination = tableState.pagination;
  start = pagination.start || 0; // This is NOT the page number, but the index of item in the list that you want to use to display the table.
  length = pagination.number || 10; // Number of entries showed per page.
  $scope.isDataLoading = true;
  AdminJobMasterService.getMasterJobs(start, length).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.rowCollection = response.data;
    $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);

    //set the number of pages so the pagination can update
    tableState.pagination.numberOfPages = response.numberOfPages;
    $scope.displayedPages = Math.ceil(response.numberOfPages / length);
    $scope.isDataLoading = false;
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.error(data);
    $scope.isDataLoading = false;
  });
};
```

Now, I call a different controller when I click the new/edit button and on click of close on the modal, I trigger the event and handle that event in the above controller. Please see that, I am resetting the collection observed by smart-table and also, tried initializing the tableState variable. Without tableState
variable, I cannot call `getMasterJobs()` as `tableState.pagination` will be `null`.

```js
$scope.$on('new-job-added', function(event, data) {
  $log.info("Time to refresh!");
  $scope.rowCollection = [];
  $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);
  var tableState = {
    sort: {},
    search: {},
    pagination: {
      start: 0
    }
  };
  $scope.getMasterJobs(tableState);
});
```

Comment: I'm now having this issue or one very similar to it. This is the first thing I've found about it. Did you happen to figure anything out?